# Sum all the numbers in a file given by positional parameter

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sum

I want to sum all the numbers in a file (columns and lines) given by the first parameter, but my program shows `sum=sum+$i` instead of the numeric sum:

```
sum=0;
file=$1

for i in $file
do
        sum=sum+$i;
done;
echo "The sum is:  " $sum
```

> Input file:

```
$cat file.txt
10 20 10
40
50
```

> Expected output :

```
The sum is: 21
```

Maybe if there is an awk method to solve this?

Comment: Post sample data and it's expected result. Go.

Comment: in file.txt
first line:10 20 10
second line: 40
third line: 50

expected result: 130

Comment: I have also tried this awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum=sum+($i)} END {print "The sum is:" sum}' $1 , but it sums only the first numbers in a line

Comment: Integers? Floats? Could you please post the complete text of your assignment?

Comment: Show the sum of all integers in a file. The file can contain multiple lines and in each line can be multiple integers.

Comment: Show the sum of all integers in a file. The file can contain multiple lines and in each line can be multiple integers @MarkPlotnick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$cat file1.txt
10 20 10
40
50
$awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sum+=$i}} END {print sum}' file1.txt
130
```

OR

```
$xargs  < file1.txt| tr ' ' + | bc
130
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt | xargs | sed -e 's/\ /+/g' | bc
```

Comment: You don't need cat here - 

`$xargs < file1.txt|sed -e 's/\ /+/g' | bc`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple `read` and an `array` to sum the value relying on *word splitting* to separate the values into an array via the default `IFS` (*Internal Field Separator*), e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i sum=0
fn="${1:-/dev/stdin}"       ## read from file as 1st argument (default stdin) 

while read -r line; do      ## read each line
    a=( $line )             ## separate values into array
    for i in ${a[@]}; do    ## for each value in array
        ((sum += i))        ## add to sum
    done
done <"$fn"

echo "sum: $sum"
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/numfile.txt
10 20 10
40
50
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash sumnumfile.sh dat/numfile.txt
sum: 130
```

Comment: Thanks :) @David C. Rankin

Comment: Sure, I like looking at all of the answers. There are an number of different ways to skin this cat. All good and valid, and all good to add to the bash/shell toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Another for some awks (at least mawk and gawk):

```
$ awk -v RS="[^0-9]" '{s+=$1}END{print s}' file   
130
```